# How do I add a Device Kit to an existing project

Tags: application-development, qml

I am writing a QML Ubuntu Application and unfortunately forgot to check the boxes for the different Device Kits when I created the Project.

How do I get those Device Kits to show up at the run menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your project opened in Qt Creator, select the *Projects* tab on the left-hand side.  This will give you several tabs across the top.  *Build & Run* should already be selected.  Just under this there is an *Add Kit* button.  Click it, and a list of kits you can add to the current project will drop down.  Select the one you want to add, and you should be all set.